# Calling data from the API for child component in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a header component. Here is the code:

```
import style from '../../styles/header.css';
import '../../styles/globals.css';

export default function Header({data}){
    const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
   
    function toggle(){
        console.log("toggle")
        setShowMe(!showMe);
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div className="header">
          <div className="web-header">
          <div className="first-header">
                <div className="info-strip">
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          Contact Us
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          7 Day Returns
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          Track Order
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          Return Order
                      </li>
                     
                      <li>
                         Survey
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="right-block d-flex">
                    <div className="login">
                        <span className="image"></span>
                        <span className="text">Log In
                            <div className="account-box">
                                
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="cart">
                        <span className="cart-image">
                            
                        </span>
                        <span className="text">Cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="second-header">
                <div className="header-logo">
                    
                        <img src="https://www.mirraw.com/assets/logo-red.png" />
                   
                </div>
                <div className="search">
                    <input placeholder="Search Something.." />
                    <button></button>
                </div>
               
            </div>
         
            <div className="third-header">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <ul className="menu">
                        {data.menus.map((post, index) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="menu-list">
                                    {post.title}
                                    <div className="megabox">
                                        <ul className="wrapper">
                                            {post.menu_columns.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
                                                return <li>
                                                    <span className="menu-link">
                                                        {subItems.title}
                                                    </span>
                                                    <ul className="category">
                                                        {subItems.menu_items.map((x) => {
                                                            return <li>
                                                                {x.title}
                                                            </li>
                                                        })}
                                                    </ul>
                                </li>;
                                             })}
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>)})}
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mobile-screen">
              <div className="mobile-header">
                  <div className="mobile-menu">
                      <div className="menu-icon">
                      <div className="wrapper">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="navigation" />
                          <label for="navigation">
                               +
                          </label>
                          <div className="right-card">
                              <img src="https://www.mirraw.com/assets/logo-red.png" />
                              <p className="app-install">
                                  <span>Download app</span>
                                  
                             </p>
                              <div className="cart">
                                    <span className="cart-image"></span>
                                    {/* <span className="text">Cart</span> */}
                              </div>
                          </div>
                                <nav>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li className="menu-heading">
                                            <span>Menu</span>
                                            <span>
                                                <label for="navigation">X</label>
                                            </span>
                                            
                                        </li>
                                        {data.menus.map((post, index) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="menu-list">
                                    {post.title} <span onClick={toggle}>+</span>
                                        <ul style={{display: showMe?"block":"none"}} className="category-one">
                                            {post.menu_columns.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
                                                return <li>
                                                    {subItems.title}
                                                    <span>+</span>
                                                    <ul className="category-two">
                                                        {subItems.menu_items.map((x) => {
                                                            return <li>
                                                                {x.title}
                                                            </li>
                                                        })}
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>;
                                             })}
                                        </ul>
                                    
                                </li>)})}
                                        
                                       
                                       
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="scroll-menu-list">
                            <ul className="mb-0">
                                {data.menus.map((post, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <li className="menu-list">{post.title}</li>
                                )})}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
              
            </div>
            </>
    )
} 

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Fetch data from external API
   
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.mirraw.com/api/v1/menu`);
    
    const data = await res.json();
  
    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { data } }
  }
```

Code is working fine if I render this page only, but when I import this component in other component, it threw error:

> Server Error
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'menus' of undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

What could be the approach of getting value from the API for child component?

Answer (score 0):

[`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) can only be used within page components, which is why it works when you render this component as a page.

If you want to this to be a reusable component that can be called from other components and/or pages you'll need to pass the data you get at the page level (from `getServerSideProps`, for instance) down to it.

```js
// pages/index.js

import Header from "../components/header"

export default function IndexPage({ data }) { 
    return (
        <Header data={data} />
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.mirraw.com/api/v1/menu`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return { props: { data } }
}
```